# Adding variable to database with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How can I add record into my database? I am afraid, that when i do it like this, in database there will be cell containing "veriable1", not veriable1 content. Is this correct?

```
public class Record
{
    public Record(String veriable1, String veriable2) throws IOException, SQLException
        {
           addRecord();
        }

        private void addRecord() throws IOException, SQLException
        {   
            try
            {
                Statement stat = DataBase.Connect().createStatement();

                stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tableName "
                                 + "(veriable1, veriable2) "
                                 + "VALUES "
                                 + "(veriable1, veriable2)");
            }
            finally
            {
                BazaDanych.Polacz().close();
            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (should) use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for this.

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO tableName (variable1, variable2) VALUES (?, ?)";
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
    statement.setString(1, variable1);
    statement.setString(2, variable2);
    statement.executeUpdate();
} finally {
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

If offers the advantage that any potential [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) will be eliminated, in contrary to when using string concatenation as suggested by other answers.

Also note that I slightly rewrote the way how the resources are handled. The above way is the standard JDBC idiom. It ensures that the `PreparedStatement` is also closed before the `Connection` is closed, otherwise you will run out of resources when the `Connection` concerns a pooled connection.

#### See also:

- [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) - [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) - [Prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the variable itself inside the SQL statement ,see this

```
 stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tableName "
                             + "(veriable1, veriable2) "
                             + "VALUES "
                             + "("+veriable1+", "+veriable2+")");
        }
```